# What's the difference between these two Scala patterns?

Tags: scala

In Scala 2.10.6, what's the difference between an object that will not match

```
case Array((_, workItem: WorkItem)) =>
```

but will match

```
case things: Array[_] => things.foreach { case (_, workItem: WorkItem) =>
```

I'm seeing this occur. Some objects will match the first one, others will not match the first form but will match the second. Without the second form, a MatchError is thrown:

```
scala.MatchError: [Lscala.Tuple2;@43d82d2a (of class [Lscala.Tuple2;)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first is matching an `Array[(_, WorkiItem)]` with exactly one element, the second matches any `Array` and will not throw MatchError in the `foreach` if all of its elements are  `(_, WorkItem)`